# SELECT MAX() value from row data converted into column data using UNPIVOT and SELECT MAX()

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, max

I have a table called amounts that looks like this:

```
// structure 1
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| MON | TUE | WED | THU | FRI | SAT | SUN |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 1   | 6   | 3   | 1   | 1   | 3   | 0   |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

I need to grab the `MAX()` value from the row above (the table only has one row).

How could I `PIVOT` the table so that it reads like this:

```
// structure 2
+-----+-----+
| DAY | AMT |
+-----+-----+
| MON | 1   |
+-----+-----+
| TUE | 6   |
+-----+-----+
| WED | 3   |
+-----+-----+
| THU | 1   |
+-----+-----+
| FRI | 1   |
+-----+-----+
| SAT | 3   |
+-----+-----+
| SUN | 0   |
+-----+-----+
```

... and then select the `MAX()` value of the `AMT` column:

```
SELECT MAX(AMT)
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM amounts
) AS amts
PIVOT (
    AMT FOR * IN ... // got stuck here, pivots are confusing
) AS highest_amt
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: There are tons of answers out there in google!!

Comment: What do you expect to get if you have more than 1 row? The operator you are looking for is called `UNPIVOT` btw

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, There is only one row in the amounts table, it is actually a view created for reporting purposes

Comment: @proPhet Which means there are a lot of data aggregated to a single row. Unpivoting could result in an inefficient execution plan in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to unpivot the results. In your case where the results come from a reporting view, this could result in an inefficient execution plan.

You can use the `VALUES` constructor to create a table of values from the view's columns then get the maximum value like this:

```
select MAX(dayvalues.v)
from 
amounts          
CROSS APPLY (VALUES  (amounts.MON),(amounts.TUE),(amounts.WED),(amounts.THU),
                     (amounts.FRI),(amounts.SAT),(amounts.SUN)
            ) dayvalues(v)
```

`VALUES` will create a table from the values found in `amounts` then `MAX` will select the maximum value. `CROSS APPLY` applies the table-valued function on its right (VALUES) on every row found on the left.

This means that the view is executed only once

Comment: this is elegant, efficient, and would work for any number rows unlike some other answers here.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is `unpivot` not `pivot`!!

**Pivot - rows to column**

**UnPivot - column to row**

try this..

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
  (
     MON INT,
     TUE INT,
     WED INT,
     THU INT,
     FRI INT,
     SAT INT,
     SUN INT
  )

INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES     (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

SELECT *
FROM   #temp

;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT value,
                col,
                Row_number()
                  OVER(
                    ORDER BY value DESC) rn
         FROM   #temp
                UNPIVOT ( value
                        FOR col IN (MON,
                                    TUE,
                                    WED,
                                    THU,
                                    FRI,
                                    SAT,
                                    SUN ) ) unpiv)
SELECT value,
       COL AS AMT
FROM   cte
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Comment: The data comes from a reporting view. Unpivoting it could result in bad performance if it interferes with the execution plan of the view

Answer (score 1):

The efficient way I could imagine is to max every column separately, then union to get the max value.

```
with t(v) as(
    select max(MON) from amounts 
    union
    select max(TUE) from amounts 
    union ... 
    select max(SUN) from amounts 
)
select max(v)
from t
```

It could be improved like this:

```
with 
    m   as(
    select 
        max(MON) as MON,
        ...
        max(SUN) as SUN
    from amounts 
    )
   ,t(v) as(
    select MON from m
    union
    select TUE from m
    union ... 
    select SUN from m
)
select max(v)
from t
```

**UPDATE**

I realized that SQL SERVER will  run the same view 7 times according to  @PanagiotisKanavos's comment. But in other DBMS such as ORACLE will only take one table scan first to aggregate 7 columns, it can really save time for this case.

Fortunately `values` clause can do the trick in SQL SERVER, join 7 columns after aggregation will be more efficient than cross join before aggregation. You could compare the query plan using [this **SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b4869/2).

```
with m as(
    select 
        max(MON) as MON,
        max(TUE) as TUE,
        ...
        max(SUN) as SUN
    from amounts 
    )
select 
    (select max(v) 
         from 
             (values
                 (m.MON)
                ,(m.TUE)
                ...
                ,(m.SUN)
             )t(v)
    )
from m;
```

Comment: The data comes from a reporting view. This would have awful performance

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos How about the second sql?

Comment: Worse most probably - you still run the same view 7 times (one for each union). Adding the aggregate does nothing at best as the view returns a single row already

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sorry I didn't check the query plan in SQL SERVER, but it really works in other DBMS such as ORACLE and DB2. And I found another solution and updated my answer, I think this way is really better.

Comment: Are you sure about the other RDBMSs? The query optimizer in all of them will have to decide what to do with 7 different aggregate operations that have to be unioned. Will *any* of them convert it to a single aggregation? It's not that SQL Server is dumb (actually it has a much better optimizer) but that you force multiple aggregations on top of a view without checking the resulting execution plan

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes I'm sure. I checked query plans of my second SQL in ORACLE and Postgres with sql fiddle. And I checked query plan in DB2 in my office just now. In DB2 `with` clause will create a temp table instead of a view in SQL Server, that the difference I didn't know. And multiple aggregations in one table only need one table scan even in Sql Server. Force it on top can reduce the overhead of cross join, according to the query plan in my sql fiddle demo, my approach will take almost 100% overhead in table scan, and your approach less than 96%, there are only few rows.